# Spring global exception handler not being invoked

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

Just started looking into Spring and made a FizzBuzz rest api. when I added a `ControllerAdvice` I realized it doesn't catch any of the exceptions I throw and instead they go to the default handler. I tried many suggestions but so far nothing works. am I doing anything wrong or not doing something ?

```
package com.fizzbuzz;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler;

import com.fizzbuzz.Exceptions.ForbiddenUseException;
import com.fizzbuzz.Exceptions.IllegalParameterException;

import helpers.*;

import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;

@ControllerAdvice
public class ErrorHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    org.slf4j.Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ErrorHandler.class);

    /** Just exploring how global exception handlers operate **/

    @ExceptionHandler(ForbiddenUseException.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<ApiError> GeneralError(ForbiddenUseException ex){
        ApiError error = new ApiError(ex.getMessage(), "FRB-123");
        return new ResponseEntity<ApiError>(error, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(IllegalParameterException.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<ApiError> ParameterError(IllegalParameterException ex){
        ApiError error = new ApiError(ex.getMessage(), "PAR-123");
        return new ResponseEntity<ApiError>(error, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<ApiError> InternalServerError (Exception ex){
        /** Log 
         *  Add stack trace or anything deemed useful here
         **/
        log.debug("Internal server error: " + ex.getMessage());
        /** don't show any specifics about the exceptions here should be logged instead **/
        ApiError error = new ApiError("Whoops something nasty happened, check server logs for details.", "IS-001");
        return new ResponseEntity<ApiError>(error, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

}
```

And this is the controller

```
package com.fizzbuzz.Controllers;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.fizzbuzz.Exceptions.ForbiddenUseException;
import com.fizzbuzz.Exceptions.IllegalParameterException;

import helpers.*;

@RestController
public class FizzBuzzControllers {

    /** 
     *  FizzBuzz crashes in case of bad input or cast
     *  Exception handling in global handler @ErrorHandler
     * @throws ForbiddenUseException When parameter is empty or null
     * @throws IllegalParameterException list contains something other than numbers
     **/
    @PostMapping("/FizzBuzz")
    String FizzBuzz(@RequestBody String list) throws ForbiddenUseException, IllegalParameterException {
        List<String> response = new ArrayList<String>();
        if(list == null || list.isEmpty())
            throw new ForbiddenUseException("The list of numbers cannot be empty or null.");
        for (String token : list.split(",")) {
            try
            {
                response.add(Helpers.FizzBuzz(Integer.parseInt(token)));
            } catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
                /** Found some nonsense in the list throw an exception **/
                throw new IllegalParameterException("The list can't contain anything other than numbers.");
            }
        }
        return String.join(",", response);
    }

    /** 
     *  FizzBuzz v2 tries to recover from bad input by adding N/A when encountering incorrect entries
     *  w/e other exception is handled @ErrorHandler as 500 internal server error
     *  @throws ForbiddenUseException When parameter is empty or null
     **/
    @PostMapping("/FizzBuzzV2")
    String FizzBuzzv2(@RequestBody String list) throws ForbiddenUseException {
        List<String> response = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        if(list == null || list.isEmpty())
            throw new ForbiddenUseException("The list of numbers cannot be empty or null.");
        for (String token : list.split(",")) {
            try
            {
                response.add(Helpers.FizzBuzz(Integer.parseInt(token)));
            } catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
                /** Found some nonsense in the list add N/A and continue **/
                response.add("N/A");
            }
        }
        return String.join(",", response);
    }
}
```

The two custom exception have nothing but `super(message)` in the constructor. everything other than exception handling works just fine.

I have added this to the main method to display all the beans and it does show the exception handler among them, so i guess that means spring knows about it.

```
for (String beanName : applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
            System.out.println(beanName);
        }
```

Comment: Is your `ErrorHandler` class in a package that is scanned for components by Spring?

Comment: it's in the same package as the `@SpringBootApplication` class

Comment: Then that should not be the problem (unless you've customized the way Spring Boot looks for Spring beans).

Comment: i have no idea how to do that. i did not change anything in the configuration i just wrote the classes. where can i check how the beans are handled ?

Comment: in the project explorer i can see the `errorHandler` under the Beans forlder